# When should I use あそこで / そこで?

Tags: grammar, jlpt, linguistics

I have the sentence from 合格できる、日本語能力試験N２:

> 私は外国旅行をするたび、「　」専門の勉強をしている日本人の若い学者に会うと、思いがけない収穫をえる。

The choices for the blank are A）あそこで　B）そこで　C）ここで　D）どこかで

I narrowed it down to either A or B, but then I realized that I don't know the difference between them. Would someone mind explaining when either should be used and the difference they make?

Comment: I think it's like... "魚民の看板を見るたび、「その」(not「あの」)文字間がくっつき気味なデザインに惑わされる。" / "茂木さんのツイート見るたび、「その」(not 「あの」)話題について考え込んでしまう。" / "被災者の方々の様子を報道で見るたび「そこで」(not あそこで)過ごしている方や・・・"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you want an anaphoric usage of demonstrative pronoun, not a deictic one. I think only ここ and そこ allow anaphoric usage.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, since the author had mentioned the place already (and to avoid repetition), an anaphoric そこで is used. If the place was already known by the listener (inference), then a deictic あそこで could be used. Does this seem correct?

Comment: @Chris It is not to avoid repetition. It is because it is a varibale. It is like "whenever I travel x, ... x ...". The x here needs the binder "whenever x". Without it, it cannot be interpreted. Deictic usage requires a different context.